# "Module openfl.display.Shader does not define type Shader" when trying to do a release for neko or windows [Flash Develop/Haxe]

Tags: haxe, flashdevelop, openfl, haxeflixel

this is somenthing I was trying to solve for HOURS, but I don't get why this is not working.

First of all, I'm trying to do a release for neko or windows in Flash Develop. My project is a OpenFl one, and the language is Haxe 3.

What I have installed:

- actuate: [1.8.6]
- flixel-addons: [2.3.0]
- flixel: [4.2.1]
- hxcpp: [3.4.64]
- lime: [2.9.1]
- nape: [2.0.20]
- openfl: [3.6.1]

And yes; I'm using haxeFlixel.

When I try to do a release in windows or neko, these errors appear:

-E:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/3,6,1/openfl/_internal/renderer/opengl/utils/SpriteBatch.hx:12: characters 7-28 : Module openfl.display.Shader does not define type Shader

-E:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/3,6,1/openfl/_internal/renderer/opengl/utils/SpriteBatch.hx:12: characters 7-28 : For function argument 'ax'

-src/skill/SkillLogicProjectil.hx:13: lines 13-54 : Defined in this class

-E:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/openfl/3,6,1/openfl/_internal/renderer/opengl/shaders2/Shader.hx:11: characters 7-28 : Module openfl.display.Shader does not define type Shader

The most funny thing is: I'm not even using Shader in SkillLogicProjectil. That class only creates a sprite that follows a Player and has a var with the sprite that represents the skill.
If I comment this class, the error is in another class, and finally ends in my GameState.

This error doesn't appear when I do a release in html5. In html5 there are no problems with the release, but I can´t make the game load without Flash Develop running the process in http://localhost:2000/. I need to make a release that can be opened with a computer, without using Flash Develop to open it.

What can I do?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of Flixel supports Haxe 3.4.3 and OpenFL 8, have you given these versions a try?

Comment: Actually this worked. I'm leaving here what I have now. Thanks!.

actuate: [1.8.6]
flixel-addons: 2.3.0 [2.6.0]
flixel: 4.2.1 [4.4.1]
hxcpp: [3.4.64]
lime: 2.9.1 [6.3.1]
nape: [2.0.20]
openfl: 3.6.1 [8.0.0]